# PIP not available from command line

Tags: python, linux, centos, python-3.6

I am using CentOS. It has Python 3.6 version installed.

From command line if I try to execute PIP, I get error: "Command not found"

How to add Python folder to the environment path?

Comment: Did you try running `python3 -m pip`?

Comment: Looks like you don't have pip3 installed

Comment: try this:   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pip is not available in CentOS 7 core repositories. To install pip we need to enable the EPEL repository:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

Once the EPEL repository is enabled we can install pip and all of its dependencies with the following command:

```
sudo yum install python-pip
```

To verify that the pip is installed correctly run the following command which will print the pip version:

```
pip --version
```

Enjoy! :)

Comment: One more issue is that both 3.6 and 3.8 versions are installed. However, when I just type Python from command line, the 3.6 version opens and not 3.8. How to make 3.8 default?

Comment: I executed: sudo yum install python-pip. It is trowing error: unable to find a match: python-pip

Comment: @RKh Make sure you run "sudo yum install epel-release" before "sudo yum install python-pip"

Comment: I executed "yum -y update". It says: "Dependencies resolved. Nothing to do."

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you should install pip separately in CentOS.
Try this [Link](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-pip-on-centos-7/).